# How to create a specific Discord bot that can create a note on a discord account which anyone/any admins can read

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to create a discord bot in which you can create a note on accounts. Say i wanna make a not on user user#1111, i would do something like `!note @user#1111 New note`. I want to make it in python but im not too sure if i can do it on there? Thanks!

Comment: You can create entries in a database and add them on command. If you want to output them, request them from the database. A JSON or mysql or similiar could fit.

Answer (score -3):

*Edit: Anyways, my answer was really bad since I provided a false example. Well, it is because I don’t really use SQL, I only know how to use to replit database. And **if you are on replit, the following code will work for you**; if not, you **can’t** use this code.*

```py
import discord
from replit import db
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="n!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.command()
async def note(ctx, user: discord.User, *, content):
  if str(user.id) not in db.keys(): # If the user ID is not in the keys of the database:
    db[str(user.id)] = {str(ctx.author.id):content}
  else:
    dic = db[str(user.id)]
    dic[str(ctx.author.id)] = content
    db[str(user.id)] = dic
  await ctx.send(f"Saved your note for {user}: {content}")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

## Old answer (bad)

---

You can use a database like SQL. You can just make a command and saves the content entered after the command to the database. This is my example (I am using replit instead of SQL. **Don’t use this.**):

```py
import discord
from replit import db
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="n!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.command()
async def note(ctx, user: discord.User, content):
  db[str(user.id)] = {str(ctx.author.id):content}

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

**MY EXAMPLE IS REALLY BAD. IT WILL OVERRIDE THE DATABASE EVERYTIME SOMEONE USES THE COMMAND. DON’T COPY THIS CODE. TRY TO CODE IT YOURSELF.**

Comment: Thanks! Ill try to see if i can do that!

Comment: Just make sure don’t use this code on your real bot.

Comment: If you recommend not to use this, why are you providing this as an answer to the question? That is not really helpful nor does it answer the question...

Comment: I don’t want them to just copy code right away :(

Comment: Anyways, they should learn some SQL and use the sqlite3 module to use SQL databases.

Comment: Pro tip for answering: Try to make an answer that works for OP or at least make a workable example code which can be changed and used without any issue. Putting warning flags to not use your answer, makes it a really low quality / low effort answer. A good answer includes a lot of details and is helpful to OP and other who may encounter a similar problem.